# How can I merge and match 2 separate objects?

Tags: javascript, join, javascript-objects, array-merge

#### What I want

I have **2 different Java-Script arrays/objects** but with **matching Ids**. I want to merge them into a new object. So both the main object data and any matched elements from the secondary object are merged into a combined result.

#### What I tried

I tried using `Object.assign()` function but with no success.

#### Given Input

Example code, so I have 2 separate objects (*main* and *lines*):

```
let main = [
    {
        "Id": "1",
        "Name": "Testing data"
    }
]

let lines = [
    {
        "OtherId": "1",
        "code": "AU-29830"
    },
    {
        "OtherId": "1",
        "code": "AU-29854-Single"
    },
    {
        "OtherId": "1",
        "code": "TV-BB21084623"
    },
    {
        "OtherId": "2",
        "code": "Don't Merge"
    },
    {
        "OtherId": "3",
        "code": "Don't Merge"
    }
]
```

#### Expected Output

I want to merge those 2 arrays, so that the output should be a **single array** containing the **merged** *main-object*. This *merged main-object* should contain the original content of itself plus nested the **filtered** *secondary array* (only containing **matching objects**). The filtering was done using the **id** from the *main array's object* which has to match (the *slightly deviating* id) from each object of the *secondary-array*.

The resulting array should look like this:

```
let result = [
   {
        "Id": "1",
        "Name": "Testing data",
        "lines": [
            {
                "OtherId": "1",
                "ProductCode": "AU-29830"
            },
            {
                "OtherId": "1",
                "ProductCode": "AU-29854-Single"
            },
            {
                "OtherId": "1",
                "ProductCode": "TV-BB21084623"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: You gave input and output and described your requirements very detailed. In appreciation I reformatted and rewrote a bit. Only what you tried to solve it, some pseudo-code is missing. Thus we have no starting base from which we could guide you to the solution. Please add a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your `main` is an array, I'm assuming you might end up with more than one main item in it. If so, here's one way to merge your `line` items onto each one:

```
const mergedMainItems = 
    main.map(mainItem=>({
        ...mainItem, 
        lines: lines.filter(line=>mainItem["Id"] === line["OtherId"])
    }))
```

Comment: Concise solution! Anyway, since OP had difficulties describing required transformation steps himself/herself and you _assumed context_, it would be nice to add some __explanation of steps__ led to your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think for this example this will work:

```js
let result = [];
result.push({...main[0]}); //or even result.push(main[0])
result[0].lines = [];
for(let l in lines){
  if(lines[l].code != "Don't Merge"){
    result[0].lines.push({OtherId: lines[l].OtherId, ProductCode: lines[l].code})
  }
}
```